# What is the id property that comes with StreamCreated event listener

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm registering for this event:

`guildUser.Guild.AudioClient.StreamCreated += StreamCreated;`

which has a signature:

`event Func<ulong, AudioInStream, Task> StreamCreated;`

However, I haven't had any luck figuring out what id this ulong corresponds to. I want to associate the stream created event to the guild/channel that was connected.

I've tried matching it to the Guild.Id, the Voice Channel Id, the Guild AudioClient (doesn't have an Id).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the value is the userId for each stream that was created. I used the following to figure out what channel that user is currently connected to.

`var voiceChannels = channels.Where(x => x.Users.Where(z => z.Id == userId).Any()).Select(z => z as SocketVoiceChannel).Where(y => y != null).First();`